# Applying skeleton to procedural skinned mesh

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koob3d/yauwxmmy/) I'm trying to create a procedural worm (or snake or caterpillar) character, based on the basic bones example at threejs.org/docs/scenes/bones-browser, but with an extra four bones and two spheres for eyes added on; the added/altered code shown here...

function eyeBall() {

```
function eyeBall(  ) {

    var faceIndices = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
    var color, f, i, j, p, vertexIndex, radius = 1;
    var geometry  = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 18, 5 );

    for ( i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {
        f  = geometry.faces[ i ];
        for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
            vertexIndex = f[ faceIndices[ j ] ];
            p = geometry.vertices[ vertexIndex ];
            f.color = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
            if( p.y < -0.9 ) { 
                f.color = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
            }
        }
    }
    return geometry;
}
```

function createBones ( sizing ) {

```
function createBones ( sizing ) {

    bones = [];

    var prevBone = new THREE.Bone();
    bones.push( prevBone );
    prevBone.position.z = - sizing.halfLength;

    for ( var i = 0; i < sizing.segmentCount; i ++ ) {

        var bone = new THREE.Bone();
        bone.position.z = sizing.segmentLength;
        bones.push( bone );
        prevBone.add( bone );
        prevBone = bone;
    }

    //add more bones
    var lHdBone = new THREE.Bone();
        lHdBone.position.set( 1.4, 0, 2.8 );
        lHdBone.name = 'lHdBone';
        bones.push( lHdBone );
        prevBone.add( lHdBone );

    var rHdBone = new THREE.Bone();
        rHdBone.position.set( -1.4, 0, 2.8 );
        rHdBone.name = 'rHdBone';
        bones.push( rHdBone );
        prevBone.add( rHdBone );

    var lEyeBone = new THREE.Bone();
        lEyeBone.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        lEyeBone.name = 'lEyeBone';
        bones.push( lEyeBone );
        lHdBone.add( lEyeBone );

    var rEyeBone = new THREE.Bone();
        rEyeBone.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        rEyeBone.name = 'rEyeBone';
        bones.push( rEyeBone );
        rHdBone.add( rEyeBone );

    return bones;
}
```

function initBones () {

```
function initBones () {

    var segmentLength = 8;
    var segmentCount = 4;
    var length = segmentLength * segmentCount;
    var halfLength = length * 0.5;

    var sizing = {
        segmentLength : segmentLength,
        segmentCount : segmentCount,
        length : length,
        halfLength : halfLength
    };

    var geometry = createGeometry( sizing );
    var bones = createBones( sizing );
    mesh = createMesh( geometry, bones );

    var lEye = eyeBall();
    var rEye = eyeBall();
    lEye.rotateX(  -Math.PI * 0.5);
    rEye.rotateX( -Math.PI * 0.5);
    lEye.translate( 1.4, 0, sizing.halfLength + 2.8 );
    rEye.translate( -1.4, 0, sizing.halfLength + 2.8 );

    var lEyeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( lEye, material );
    var rEyeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( rEye, material );

    mesh.add( lEyeMesh );
    mesh.add( rEyeMesh );

    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 1 );
    scene.add( mesh );
}
```

The animation in the fiddle moves the spheres in the same general direction but the spheres are clearly not tied to the skeleton as desired. The eyes should be looking forward throughout. I haven't found any comparable questions for this since most modelling is done in Blender, but I am sure this should be possible in three.js alone.
I feel I'm missing something simple!

[This is another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koob3d/1qmarxr4/) with merged geometries. Now one eye seems to act correctly, but the other eye is evidently a child bone; i.e. bones[6] is a child of bones[5], while they should both be children of bones[4].